# Love2D STI library not drawing map at all (black screen)

Tags: tilemap, lua, tiled, love2d

I'm trying to use a pretty standard map with the Simple Tiled Implementation module for Love2D, but no matter what I try, I can't get it to display anything but a black screen. Here's my current code (keybindings in an effort to see if the map has just been placed offscreen):

```
local sti = require "sti"
local mapPos = { x = 0, y = 0 }

function love.load()
   map = sti("maps/map1.lua")
end

function love.update(dt)
   if love.keyboard.isDown("w") or love.keyboard.isDown("up") then
      mapPos.y = mapPos.y - 5
   end

   -- Move player down
   if love.keyboard.isDown("s") or love.keyboard.isDown("down") then
      mapPos.y = mapPos.y + 5
   end

   -- Move player left
   if love.keyboard.isDown("a") or love.keyboard.isDown("left") then
      mapPos.x = mapPos.x - 5
   end

   -- Move player right
   if love.keyboard.isDown("d") or love.keyboard.isDown("right") then
      mapPos.x = mapPos.x + 5
   end
   map:update(dt)
end

function love.draw()
   -- Transform world
   love.graphics.translate(-mapPos.x, -mapPos.y)

   -- Draw world
   map:draw()
end
```

However, even a more basic attempt (copied from the STI tutorial linked from the README on the Github page) doesn't work, again giving a black screen:

```
-- Include Simple Tiled Implementation into project
local sti = require "sti"

function love.load()
    -- Load map file
    map = sti("map.lua")
end

function love.update(dt)
    -- Update world
    map:update(dt)
end

function love.draw()
    -- Draw world
    map:draw()
end
```

My directory structure is basically just `main.lua`, an assets folder, and a maps folder. The maps folder contains the Tiled tile set and the Tiled .tmx maps and the lua exported maps.

I'm on Mac OSX, using Love2D version 0.10.2.

Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, when I paste your second snippet into a `main.lua` and put it in the STI repository root, and change the map from "map.lua" to "tests/ortho.lua", and run "love .", it simply works for me. Is there no error message displayed at all? Did you try it with the example map instead of your own?

Comment: I fixed it. It was a problem with exporting my lua map.

Answer (score 1):

I realized you need to be careful exporting lua maps from Tiled, because they are automatically named like "[your map name]..lua". I'm not sure why this is, but when I did Export As instead and named the file manually, it worked.

Comment: Hmm, it's not supposed to add a double dot of course. I can't reproduce this problem on Linux. What operating system are you on?